# How to hide header.jsp and footer.jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-dialog

I had a simple jsp file which can be opened from menu as well as from a link . When opened from menu it should show header and footer but when opened from a link it should be opened like pop up where the header and footer should not be there . I am able to get the popup and jsp but unable to hide the header and footer when opened as a pop up .

```
<body style="cursor: default;" class="bodyColor" >
    <div id="pageLevel">
        <jsp:include page="../common/header.jsp"></jsp:include>
    </div>
...
<table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <td><%@include file="/jsp/common/footer.jsp"%>
                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your content in another JSP content.jsp :

JSP with header and footer :

```
<jsp:include page="header.jsp"></jsp:include>
<jsp:include page="content.jsp"></jsp:include>
<jsp:include page="footer.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

JSP without header and footer :

```
<jsp:include page="content.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

Comment: I didn't find a way to include the files at run time that made me to accept your answer . Thanks Nyamiou The Galeanthrope